# Вывод элементов из массива объектов в HTML таблицу

Tags: javascript, html, массивы, объекты

Есть вот такой вот массив объектов, нужно поместить его `name` и `song` в поля таблицы.

```js
songs = [{
    url: 'http://tegos.kz/new/mp3_full/Redfoo_-_New_Thang.mp3',
    artist: {
      name: 'Redfoo',
      song: 'New Thang'
    }
  },
  {
    url: 'http://a.tumblr.com/tumblr_lpoc6cHNDP1r0jthjo1.mp3',
    artist: {
      name: 'Hugo',
      song: '99 Problems'
    }
  }
];
```

Вот таблица HTML.

```
<div className="tracks-table">
  <table className="table">
    <tr className="mess-hide">
      <td className="name">
        <h4>{}</h4>
      </td>
      <td className="song">
        <h4>{}</h4>
      </td>
      <td className="duration">
        <h4>{}</h4>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Как сделать так что бы в подходящие поля таблицы вывелись все имена и названия песен всех массивов `songs`?
Т.е. что бы было примерно вот так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а что ето за "масив" такой ?

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych сам `songs` это массив, его элементы это объекты

Comment: так может стоит это непонятно что заменить на пример масива ?

Comment: @RostyslavKuzmovych так нормально?

Answer (score 3):

Например вот так:

```js
var songs = [{
    url: 'http://tegos.kz/new/mp3_full/Redfoo_-_New_Thang.mp3',
    artist: {
      name: 'Redfoo',
      song: 'New Thang'
    }
  },
  {
    url: 'http://a.tumblr.com/tumblr_lpoc6cHNDP1r0jthjo1.mp3',
    artist: {
      name: 'Hugo',
      song: '99 Problems'
    }
  }
];

var countSongs = songs.length;
var table = document.createElement('table');
document.write('<div className="tracks-table"><table className="table">');
for (var i = 0; i < countSongs; i++) {
  var name = songs[i].artist.name;
  var song = songs[i].artist.song;
  var url = songs[i].url;

  document.write('<tr className="mess-hide"><td className="name"><h4>' + name + '</h4></td><td className="song"><h4>' + song + '</h4></td><td className="url"><h4>' + url + '</h4></td></tr>');
}

document.write('</table></div>');
```

```css
td {
  border: 1px solid #000;
  padding: 5px
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var songs = [{
    url: 'http://tegos.kz/new/mp3_full/Redfoo_-_New_Thang.mp3',
    artist: {
      name: 'Redfoo',
      song: 'New Thang'
    }
  },
  {
    url: 'http://a.tumblr.com/tumblr_lpoc6cHNDP1r0jthjo1.mp3',
    artist: {
      name: 'Hugo',
      song: '99 Problems'
    }
  }
];

// рендерим все песни в цикле
songs.forEach(function(song) {
  var renderedRow = render('song-tpl', song.artist);
  document.getElementById('songs-list').appendChild( renderedRow );
});

// рендер темплейта
function render(id, data) {
  var tpl = document.getElementById(id);
  var tplHtml = tpl.innerHTML;
  for(var i in data) {
    var repl = new RegExp('{'+i+'}', 'g');
    tplHtml = tplHtml.replace(repl, data[i]);
  }
  return parseHTML(tplHtml);
}
// создаем dom-элементы из html-строки
function parseHTML(html) {
    var t = document.createElement('template');
        t.innerHTML = html;
    return t.content.cloneNode(true);
}
```

```css
#songs-list {
border: 1px solid #000;
border-collapse: collapse;
}
#songs-list td {
border: 1px solid #000;
}
```

```html
<div class="tracks-table">
  <table class="table" id="songs-list">
  </table>
</div>

<template id="song-tpl">
<tr class="mess-hide">
      <td class="name">
        <h4>{name}</h4>
      </td>
      <td class="song">
        <h4>{song}</h4>
      </td>
      <td class="duration">
        <h4></h4>
      </td>
    </tr>
</template>
```